Correctly reimplementing `defaultdict`
I want to re-implement defaultdict myself. In principle, this feels like a really simple question, and one I might give as a "homework assignment", but the more I dug in, the more complicated it got. My first attempt looked something like this
class DefaultDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self._factory = factory
        super().__init__()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        missing = object()
        super_value = super().get(key, missing)
        if super_value is missing:
            return self._factory()

        return super_value

However, this does not pass even the most trivial test suite of
x = DefaultDict(lambda: 'no value :(')
y = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 'no value :(')
x['a'] = 'hello'
y['a'] = 'hello'
print(x['a'] == y['a']) # True
print(x.get('a') == y.get('a')) # True
print(x['b'] == y['b']) # True
print(x.get('b') == y.get('b')) # False; x.get('b') is None

After some research, I found __missing__, but an implementation using it fails the above test suite in exactly the same way
class DefaultDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self._factory = factory
        super().__init__()

    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self._factory()

It seems to me that the only way to do this completely is to re-implement dict methods like get and pop, which I don't think should be necessary. I glanced at the C implementation of defaultdict, and as far as I can tell, it only implements __missing__ as well, so I highly doubt this is required.
What would be the most "pythonic" way to re-implement defaultdict?

The fundamental part you're missing (pardon the pun) here is that defaultdict inserts the key/val into the mapping when the default factory is invoked.

What would be the most "pythonic" way to re-implement defaultdict?

What's "pythonic" is somewhat opinion based, but I'd do it like that:
def __missing__(self, key):
    val = self[key] = self._factory()
    return val

There are some other details you'll need to fully implement defaultdict API correctly:

The default factory should not be a "private" ._factory attribute, it should be a writable .default_factory attribute. This type allows dynamically changing the factory of existing instances, not just setting it at init time.
You need to add special handling for a default factory of None (ref). This can be used to switch a defaultdict into a regular dict: when a null default factory is set, it should restore KeyError exceptions for missing keys.
The __init__ signature needs to accept and pass remaining arguments and keyword arguments on to the dict initializer. You should be able to use, for example, defaultdict(int, k=42).
The __repr__ is customized to show the default factory.


That's true, but how could that change the result of the given test case?

Wow, what an incredibly simple mistake on my part. I'm really surprised that such a mistake would cause .get to fail. Indeed an implementation of __missing__ that sets self[key] = self._factory() and returns self[key] works as I'd expect. I guess my only question would be ... why?

@ollien: It's nothing specific to get. get doesn't interact with the default factory at all. Your get test fails because the value it's looking for was supposed to be inserted by the x['b'] operation.

Ah, nice catch @user2357112. I am actually surprised that defaultdict.get returns None, rather than calling the factory method, but I guess that means my original implementation wasn't far off from reality :)
This question actually originated as a simplification of a more complex subclass I was writing, and this detail was lost in the shuffle.
